# Sum field in children objects in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, nosql

I have collections `Project`, `Group`, and `Item`. An item belongs to a group and a group belongs to a project.

The items are often updated, so they have to be in a separate collection but the groups are almost always created with the project. So I wonder if it's better to create a project schema which looks something like:

```
Project {
    'id': String,
    'name': String,
    'groups': {
        {
            'id': String,
            'total_amount': Number
        }
    },
    total_amount: Number
}
```

But I need to print total_amount both on the project and in each group. I guess it is not possible to use annotated querysets to create these sums since MongoDB does not support relational schemas. So I guess I have to update the `total_amount` field every time the `amount` field in a `Item` document is updated.

How can I make sure the `total_amount` in `Project` and `Group` is updated to reflect the total sum of the amounts in the items which belong to those projects/groups? Will the proposed schema above fit my needs? I don't think it's a big problem to imitate a relational schema using `Item.groupId` and `Group.projectId` but I'm not sure what to do about the totals.

## Edit

I could also create a template helper which loops through the children and sum the total. But I guess it's quite memory consuming to loop through all objects every time the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

A solid rule is that if `groups` are usually needed in the context of `projects`, then embedding `groups` in `projects` is the best solution.

Now, about `total_amount`: Since groups can not be shared between projects, I believe updating `total_amount` every time an item changes is totally fine. If your app is small and `items` are not updated super-often, there's nothing wrong with this (it essentially only adds 1 write operation).